# Default value for Windows Form Combo box?

Tags: winforms, combobox

I have a combo box that contains different sound values in it. Whenever I choose different value, the player would play the sound once.

However the problem is that when I launch the program, upon loading the form, I load the settings file which contains the previous stored sound value on the combo box, I used the SelectedIndex property of the combobox as the default value.

Using SelectedIndex cause the player to play the sound once when the program starts which is sort of weird in that sense.

Any idea how do I select a default value other then selectedIndex? as selectedIndex also runs the backend code for that particular value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that the code to play the sound is located in your `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler method, the solution is to only attach that handler method to the event *after* you've set the default selected index.

For example:

```
private void DoLoad()
{
  // Set the data source, and the default selection
  cbox.DataSource = YourDataSource;
  cbox.SelectedIndex = YourLastSelIndex;

  // Then attach the event handler method.
  cbox.SelectedIndexChanged += YourSelectedIndexChanged;
}
```